# How to Deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App to Apache w/ Mono w/ Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mono

So I'm currently working on writing up a ASP.NET MVC app using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise which will later be hosted on an Apache server who's owner should have have Mono and it's dependents installed per http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/

From a Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise perspective, how do I hand off the web app to the server owner so that they can easily deploy it?

I've gone through the official ASP.NET page (http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/index.html) which was linked from the MSDN VS2015 Deployment page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420390.aspx) and the only documentation that I can find is in regard to deploying to Azure/IIS, not a *nix server running Apache or anything outside of Azure or IIS. Similarly, the Mono site is lacking in info.

Ideally I would like to compile the ASP.NET into some form of executable package the Apache server owner can run that sets up the resources in the proper directory, and sets up any services required, etc. I'm open to other solutions, but the simpler it is the better (they've never used Mono before, nor have I for that matter).

To get more to the point say I have a project called MvcMovie located under ...\visual studio 2015\Projects\MvcMovie which has a ".vs” folder, a "MvcMovie” folder, and a "MvcMovie.Tests” folder, a "packages” folder, and the solution file. After I build the project do I just copy the root "MvcMovie” folder and all of its contents bar the solution file and MvcMovie.Tests folder to a particular directory within Mono using FTP or some other means?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you will need to only use features and libraries that are supported by Mono.

There is a great tool available here [moma](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/) 
That will analyse your project and tell you what you will have issues with.

Once you have a project written you should just be able to open it with mono-develop and compile it as long as you use only libraries supported by mono. I mean just copy the entire folder structure and in mono-develop go to file, open project.  I've done this with a few of my projects, and they all open and compile fine, as long as I don't use anything not supported.

If you google there are a few people trying to do this with examples as well.  I myself have only messed around with it while drinking whiskey on a Friday night for fun, so I'm no expert.  That being said, I was pleasantly surprised by how well mono worked when I played with it.  So download mono-develop and report back on your success, I'm curious to hear how your project goes.

Comment: The need to run .NET on a *nix server dissipated upon discovering a free internal hosting platform that's platform agnostic due to running on CloudFoundry and I think one or two other things. My research brought me at one point to Docker being installed on *nix server in question which seems like a better documented and generally better solution than Mono.